# gruntfile.js config using grunt-jekyll

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I am trying to configure jekyll with grunt.js.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
.._layouts
.._includes
..other
```

Here is my code for the gruntfile:

```
    jekyll: {
        dev: {
            src: '',
            dest: ['_layouts', '_includes']
        },

    },
```

This dumps the entire site in one folder named _layouts,_includes

I want to to source .html files from both the _includes and _layouts folders. I know the easy way to do this is to put them in "templates" and then have jekyll watch that, but I was wondering if I can keep to this alternative structure somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely positive this will work as the `dest` only accepts a string.  You might consider using 2 sub tasks that put the site in both `_layouts` and `_includes` directories